# script to look up google safe browsing with Pysafebrowsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

it's my second time to post my problem.

I need to look up if an url is safe by google using `Pysafebrowsing` it's a python package, so I get i different result Comparison of the original source :
https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search

My script is :

```
from pysafebrowsing import SafeBrowsing
s = SafeBrowsing(KEY)
r = s.lookup_urls([domain])
print(r)
```

Please if you have any idea help me!